# Is there a way to do datetime addition in pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

what I would like to do in pig is something that is very common in sql.
I have date field that is of the form yyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss and I have another field that contains an integer which represents an amount of hours. Is there a way to easily add the integer to the datetime field so that we get a result of what we expect with clock math.

Example: date is 2013-06-01 : 23:12:12.

Then I add 2 hours

I should get 2013-06-02 01:12:12.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the latest release of Pig(0.11.0) it should be possible. But the amount of hours(time) should be as per `ISO8601 Duration Format`. It provides class `AddDuration` which allows us to add a DateTime object with a Duration object. You can find more about AddDuration at this [page](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/AddDuration.html).

**Edit :**

Yes, you can add negative hours. I tried this on my Ubuntu box :

Input :

```
2009-01-07T01:07:01.000Z,PT1S
2008-02-06T02:06:02.000Z,PT1M
2007-03-05T03:05:03.000Z,PT-1H
```

Query :

```
grunt> a = LOAD '/pig.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (dt:datetime, dr:chararray);
grunt> b = FOREACH a GENERATE AddDuration(dt, dr) AS dt1;
grunt> dump b;
```

Output :

```
(2009-01-07T01:07:02.000Z)
(2008-02-06T02:07:02.000Z)
(2007-03-05T02:05:03.000Z)
```

Comment: Do you know if this works if I need to add negative hours too?

Comment: I'm editing my answer as I can't write, what I want to write, here. Please have a look at it.

Comment: I am trying to do this, but my version of pig does not seem to support the datetime as a variable type.

I'm trying to do this from an EMR cluster from AWS. From some googling it looks liek they are not running the latest pig. Do you think this is the reason?

Comment: Oh..yes..that is the reason..they have included it in the latest build.

Comment: You could probably try using the latest version of Pig as per this document : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/Pig_SupportedVersions.html

Comment: Okay Ill try that, but in that documentation the latest version of pig they support is .9.2.2? Do you know if datetime is a data type in that version off the top of your head? If not its okay I guess i will just have to try it out.

Comment: No..It was included only in Pig-0.11.0 and later.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32429/discussion-between-pat-rick-allen-and-tariq)